# How to convert array to tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I have two arrays

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["a", "b", "d"]
```

I want to convert it to

```
{
    a :
    {
        b :
        {
            c : null,
            d : null
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: YUI's JSON utility might be of help, I haven't put this as an answer though, because I couldn't tell you straight off the bat if it will cater to your needs. Or, come to think of it, check out YUI's augment utility, it merges objects I believe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var tree = {}

function addToTree(tree, array) { 
   for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
       tree = tree[array[i]] = tree[array[i]] || {}
   }
}

addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "c"])
addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "d"])

/*{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {},
            "d": {}
        }
    }
}*/
```

Only thing it doesn't do is set the leaves of the tree to null -- it sets them to an empty object. Is that ok?

If you want the leaves to be null, then use the following instead:

```
function addToTree(tree, array) { 
    for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
        tree = tree[array[i]] = ((i == length - 1) ? null : tree[array[i]] || {})
    }
}

// or, without the i == length - 1 check in each iteration:
function addToTree(tree, array) { 
    for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length -1; i++) {
        tree = tree[array[i]] = tree[array[i]] || {};
    } 
    tree[array[i]] = null;
}

/*{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": null,
            "d": null
        }
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `var`: `var i = 0, length = array.length`