# converting an array into a tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

can somebody explain this code? I don't get what is inside the "for" structure.

```
 var tree = {}

function addToTree(tree, array) { 
   for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
       tree = tree[array[i]] = tree[array[i]] || {}
   }
}

addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "c"])
addToTree(tree, ["a", "b", "d"])

/*{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {},
            "d": {}
        }
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Uh...does this code even work? If so then I would like to know what's going on as well.

Comment: It works converts an array into a tree, Its like an object tree, the comment code is the output for tree. This is the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3663096/2007780

Comment: I started reading your code and writing an answer, but I can't get the same answer you got!  It seems to me that when this codes runs, `tree` should be an empty object at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've expanded the body of the `for` loop and added some comments in attempt to make things more explicit.

```
for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
   // Assign the current item in the array to a variable
   var current = array[i];

   // If there is no property on the "tree" object corresponding to the value of 
   // "current", set this property to a new object
   if (!tree[current]) {
      tree[current] = {};
   }

   // Set the "tree" variable to the field in the "tree" object whose 
   // name corresponds to "current". On the next loop iteration, "tree" will
   // refer to this "child" object, resulting in a tree-like object being
   // created as we iterate.
   tree = tree[current];
}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now!  At first, I thought that we were writing over the value of tree in the global scope, but `tree` is the name of the function parameter, as well!

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Correct - that made the OP's post unnecessarily confusing, because the value of `tree` within the scope of `addToTree` will be bound to whatever was passed in, which in the original example also happens to be the global variable called `tree`.

Answer (score 1):

That's confusing before the reference to `tree` inside the function shadows the outer variable with the same name. But due to how references work in JavaScript, it ends up modifying the outer variable anyway.

Here is what it does, step by step, considering only the first call:

1. Call function with a reference to `tree` (that is `{}`) and `["a", "b", "c"]` as arguments
2. Loop the array.

   1. Check if there is already a property "a" in the tree; if not, create it with value `{}`
   2. The full tree now looks like `{ a : {} }`
   3. Now consider the tree we're working on is `tree.a` (which is empty)
   4. Check if there is already a property "b" in the current tree; if not, create it with value `{}`
   5. The full tree now looks like `{ a : { b: {} } }`
   6. Now consider the tree we're working on is `tree.a.b` (which is empty)
   7. Check if there is already a property "c" in the current tree; if not, create it with value `{}`
   8. The full tree now looks like `{ a : { b: { c: {} } } }`
   9. Now consider the tree we're working on is `tree.a.b.c` (which is empty)
3. End of function

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand it very well